# Do java finals help the compiler create more efficient bytecode?

Tags: java, optimization, micro-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does use of final keyword in Java improve the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance)

The *final* modifier has [different consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) in java depending on what you apply it to. What I'm wondering is if *additionally* it might help the compiler create more efficient bytecode. I suppose the question goes deep into how the JVM work and might be JVM specific.

So, in your expertise, do any of the following help the compiler, or do you only use them for the normal java reasons?

- Final classes
- Final methods
- Final fields
- Final method arguments

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers! Please note that, as @Zohaib suggested, my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance). I didn't search well enough before posting. I'm not deleting it because you guys made good contributions, but the answers could be merged. I'll let the "vote for close" system decide unless told otherwise.

Comment: you might find some of your asnwers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The bytecodes are not significantly more or less efficient if you use `final` because Java bytecode compilers typically do little in the way optimization.  The efficiency bonus (if any) will be in the native code produced by the JIT compiler<sup>1</sup>.

In theory, using the `final` provides a hint to the JIT compiler that should help it optimize.  In practice, recent HotSpot JIT compilers can do a better job by ignoring your hints.  For instance, a modern JIT compiler typically performs a global analysis to find out if a given method call is a call to a leaf method in the context of the application's currently loaded classes.  This analysis is more accurate than your `final` hints can be, and the runtime can even detect when a new class is loaded that invalidates the analysis ... and redo the analysis and native code generation for the affected code.

There are other semantic consequences for use of `final`:

- Declaring a variable as `final` stops you from accidentally changing it.  (And expresses your intention to the reader.)
- Declaring a method as `final` prevents overriding in a subclass.
- Declaring a class as `final` prevents subclassing entirely.
- Declaring a field as `final` stops a subclass from changing it.
- Declaring a field as `final` has important consequences for thread-safety; see [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

In the right circumstances, these can all be good.  However, it is clear that they limit your options for reuse by creating subclasses.  This needs to be considered when deciding whether or not to use `final`.

So good practice is to use `final` to (broadly speaking) express your design intentions, and to achieve other semantic effects that you require. If you use `final` solely as an optimization hint, you won't achieve much.

---

There are a couple of exceptions where `final` *could* lead to small performance improvements on some platforms.

- Under certain circumstances, declaring a field as `final` changes the way that the bytecode compiler deals with it.  I've given one example above.  Another is the "constant variable" case ([JLS 4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)) where a `static final` field's value *will be* inlined by the bytecode compiler both in the current classes, and in other classes, and this may affect the observed behavior of code.  (For example, referring to a constant variable will NOT trigger class initialization.  Hence, the addition of a `final` *may* change the order of class initialization.)
- It is conceivable that declaring a field or local parameter as `final` may allow minor JIT compiler optimization that wouldn't otherwise be done.  However, any field that can be declared as final *could* also be inferred to be effectively final by the JIT compiler.  (It is just not clear that the JIT compiler actually does this, and whether that affects the generated native code.)

However the bottom line remains the same.  You should use `final` to express your design intentions, not as an optimization hint.

---

<sup>1 - This answer assumes that we are talking about a recent JVM with a good JIT or AOT compiler.  1) The earliest Sun Java implementations didn't have a JIT compiler at all.  2)  Early Android Java implementations had compilers which did a poor job of optimizing.  Indeed the early Android developer documentation advised various source-level micro-optimizations to compensate.  This advice has since been removed.</sup>

Comment: Great response about the benefits of using final solely as a best practice. This was one of the first things I was taught on the job and it can be very powerful. Most developers I encounter do not use final or do not understand it and I find it can be very powerful and very important.

Answer (score 12):

That question has already been asked quite a lot and the answer generally is: the compiler might do some optimisations (e.g. inline constants which are final static fields) but generally you shouldn't bother with this, since those performance gains might actually not be noticable. Just use the `final` keyword for the "normal" Java reasons (make fields or parameters immutable, prevent subclassing or overriding of methods).

Comment: Actually, you are *guaranteed* that  the Java compiler *will* inline `final static` constants, provided that they are initialized with "constant expressions" as defined by the JLS.  That is a language requirement. (It is necessary to make `switch` work, for Java's version of conditional compilation and maybe other language features.)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you test it with your code.  It can make a different to the compiler in some cases however it is more likely to make a difference to the JIT.  When it comes to micro-benchmarks and micro-tuning what should make a difference and what actually makes a difference is often not the same thing and only good testing is the way to be sure.

Another problem you have is that the JVM is improving all the time and  a trick which made a big difference before may no longer apply. e.g. in Java 5.0 `Lock` was much faster than `synchronized` however in Java 6 the difference is much smaller and `synchronized` can be faster.

In generally, its a good idea to make your code simple, clear and easily maintainable and this will also result in efficient code.