# Do Java JVMs perform any specialization or partial evaluation type optimizations?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Do any of the Java JVMs implement specialization or partial evaluation type optimizations?

Does the final keyword get used for these optimizations?

Comment: I.e., do any JVMs freeze a parameter (or exploit a parameter that has been dynamically fixed with final) and generate specialized code?

Answer (score 2):

During runtime yes. In fact all known JVM flavours do it. [What does a just-in-time (JIT) compiler do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95635/what-does-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler-do)

On final keyword

[Do java finals help the compiler create more efficient bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354412/do-java-finals-help-the-compiler-create-more-efficient-bytecode)

Hope I got the question right.

Comment: Interesting links, but they neither one seems to directly answer the [primary] question. Of course "specialization or partial evaluation" is very vague ..