# TreeSet/TreeMap equivalent for HashSet/HashMap (custom hasher)

Tags: java, dictionary, set, hashtable

[`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) has a constructor that takes a comparator, meaning even if the objects you store aren't `Comparable` objects by themselves, you can provide a custom comparator.

Is there an analogous implementation of a nonordered set? (e.g. an alternative to `HashSet<T>` that takes a "hasher" object that calculates `equals()` and `hashCode()` for objects T that may be different from the objects' own implementations?)

C++ [`std::hash_set`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html) gives you this, just wondering if there's something for Java.

---

Edit: @Max brings up a good technical point about `equals()` -- fair enough; and it's true for `TreeMap` and `HashMap` keys via [`Map.containsKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29). But are there other well-known data structures out there that allow organization by custom hashers?

Comment: By the way, are you sure you aren't mixing up different object domains? Generally you don't have a problem of adding new methods into the objects that are in domain of your application. If, however you are trying to make a map of objects received from some generated Axis client (for example), then you are mixing different domains - domain of WebService and domain of your Application. Which means, that in essence you should never need what you are asking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, having a "hasher" object is not supported by the `Collections` specifications.  You can certainly implement your own collection that supports this but another way to do this is to consider the `Hasher` to be a wrapping object that you store in your `HashSet` instead.

```
Set<HasherWrapper<Foo>> set = new HashSet<HasherWrapper<Foo>>();
set.add(new HasherWrapper(foo));
...
```

The wrapper class would then look something like:

```
private class HasherWrapper<T> {
    T wrappedObject;
    public HasherWrapper(T wrappedObject) {
        this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // special hash code calculations go here
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // special equals code calculations go here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution to the question. One suggestion, you should make `wrappedObject` final. Furthermore, `wrappedObject` should be public or private with a getter.

Comment: Why final?  Does that really help that much with the hotspot?  Given that it is a private class, I would allow the outer class to just access the field without a getter.

Comment: A number of web references say that final is not necessary these days because the VMs are smart and know if something has been overridden.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance

Answer (score 4):

There is no such implementation in the standard library, but it doesn't prevent you from rolling your own. This is something i've often wanted to have myself.

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4771660 for the reason:

> We wanted to avoid the complexity. We seriously entertained this notion
> at the time the collections framework was designed, but rejected it.  The
> power-to-weight ration seemed to low.  We felt that equals was what you
> wanted 95% of the time; ==, 4%; and something else 1%.  Writing sensible
> contracts for bulk operations when is very tricky when equality predicates
> differ.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not and there can not be by specification. Moreover, you misunderstood the way `TreeSet` uses it's `Comparator`.

From [TreeSet Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

From [Comparable javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
>   as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not
>   an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a
>   NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

From [Collection javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this collection contains
>   the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this
>   collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ?
>   e==null : o.equals(e)).

Therefore, by specification there can not be any kind of class that implements `Collection<E>` interface and **fully** depend on some external Comparator-style object to insert objects. All Collections should use `equals` method of an `Object` class to verify if the object is already inserted.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you can't provide a different custom comparator which is consistent with equals.  Doesn't e2.compareTo(e1) achieve this (it just reverses the ordering, but equal items are still equal)?

Comment: Because then the specification of Collection interface will depend on the programmers implementation of named Comparator. Collection interface explicitly states that **all** of it's implementations will consider objects equal if `a.equals(b)`. If you implement some kind of Collection that ignores or partially ignores that rule (like the case the author specified) - you will be breaking the specification of Collection interface. Even if you write in documentation "Passed comparator **must** be cosistent with equals!!" - specification will still remain broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely nothing like that, `hashcode()` and `equals()` are defining attributes of an object and should not be changed. They define what makes an object equal to each other and this shouldn't be different from one set to another. The only way to do what you are talking about is to subclass the object and write a new `hashcode()` and `equals()` and this would only really make sense to do if the subclass had a defining variable that should be added in addition to the super class' `hashcode()` and `equals()`. I know this may not be what you are aiming for but I hope this helps. If you explain your reasoning more for wanting this then it might help to find a better solution if there exists one.

Comment: Actually, how you decide to do hashing and comparing objects in your program are not defining attributes of the objects, but of the program. There is nothing wrong with wanting to use a different hashing algorithm that you know is better for your particular problem set, or considering objects equal if they have the same name, or the same id, or something else. It depends on the program, and this is an area where Java's design leaves a lot to be desired.