# Shenandoah Garbage Collector Load Reference Barriers

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, shenandoah

It is not a big secret for people who have watched the development of `Shenandoah` that a major criticism is that it employs `GC barriers` for *every single* write and read : be it reference or primitive.

`Shenandoah 2.0` claims that this is not a problem anymore and it is solved via so-called *load reference barriers*. How is this exactly happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that the reader knows what a barriers is and why it is needed. For a very short intro [here is another answer of mine on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044616/whats-the-mark-compact-algorithm-used-by-hotspot/59141137#59141137).

In order to properly understand that, we need to first look at where the initial problem really was. Let's take a rather simple example:

```
static class User {
     private int zip;
     private int age;
}

static class Holder {
    
     private User user;
     // other fields we don't care about
      
}
```

And now let's image a theoretical method like this:

```
public void access(Holder holder){
     User user = holder.user;
     for(;;){ // some loop here
         int zip = user.zip;
         System.out.println(zip);

         user.age = // some value taken from the loop for example
     }
}
```

The idea is not to show a *correct* example, but an example that does:

- a *read* (`user.zip;`)
- a *write* (`user.age = ...`)

Now because `Shenandoah 1.0` needed to introduce barriers *everywhere*, this code would look:

```
public void access(Holder holder){
  User user = RB(holder).user;  
  for(;;){ // some loop here
      int zip = RB(user).zip;
      System.out.println(zip);

      WB(user).age = // some value taken from the loop for example
  }
}
```

Notice the `RB(holder).user` (`RB` stands for `read barrier`) and `WB(user).age` (`WB` stands for `write barrier`). Now imagine that the loop is `hot` - you will pay the price for so many barriers. Even if there is no GC activity during the execution of the loop, the barriers are *still* in place and there has to be code that *conditionally* checks if the barrier needs to be executed or not.

Long story short: those barriers are not free, by any means.

These barriers are needed to maintain heap consistency, because there are *two* copies of an Object in memory during *evacuation phase*, you need to always read and write consistently. *Consistently* here means that in `Shenandoah 1.0` a *read* could have happened from the "to-space" or "from-space" (called "weak to-space invariant"), while a *write* could happen from `to-space` *only*.

---

`Shenandoah 2.0` says that it will ensure a so-called "to-space invariant" (as opposed to the previous *weak* one). Basically - it says that all the writes and reads are going to happen from/into the "to-space". During evacuation there are two copies of the Object: one in the old region (called "from-space") and one in the new region (called "to-space").

It achieves this "to-space" invariant with a rather simple, yet brilliant idea. Instead of employing barriers where `writes` happen, it ensures that the Object that was initially loaded was for sure loaded from the "to-space". This is done via *load-reference-barriers*. This is far more trivial to understand via refactoring the previous example:

```
  public void access(Holder holder){
      User user = LRB(holder).user;  
      for(;;){ // some loop here
          int zip = user.zip;
          System.out.println(zip);

          user.age = // some value taken from the loop for example
      }
  }
```

We have introduced the `LRB` barrier and removed two other. So, load-reference-barriers happen when an object is loaded, they call this : *at the definition site*, instead of when reading or storing to it, they call this *at their use-site*. You can think about it as if these barriers are inserted where `aload` and `getField` (for references) is used.

Comment: I have gained more insight into Shenandoah in the past 15 minutes through reading your answers than I have in the past few hours of googling. Thank you!