# Shenandoah self healing barriers

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, shenandoah

The title pretty much says it all - what are these *self healing* barriers and why are they important in Shenandoah 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explanation will piggy-back on [the first part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975139/shenandoah-garbage-collector-load-reference-barriers/63975140#63975140) and [the second part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002388/shenandoah-2-0-elimination-of-forwarding-pointer/64002389#64002389) of some answers I tried to put around `Shenandoah 2.0`.

To really answer this question we need to look at how the `load reference barrier` is implemented and how a `GC cycle` acts, in general.

When a certain `GC cycle` is triggered, it first chooses the *regions* with the most garbage; i.e.: objects that are in the *collection set* are very few (this will matter in the future).
The simplest way to understand this topic is via an example. Suppose this is a scheme that now exists in a certain region:

```
refA refB            
    |               
---------
|  mark |                    
---------          
| i = 0 |          
| j = 0 |          
---------
```

There is an object that exists in the region and there are two references pointing to it : `refA` and `refB`. `GC` kicks in and this region is chosen to be garbage collected. *At the same time* there are active threads in the application that try to access this Object via `refA` and `refB`. Since this object is `alive` at some point it needs to be *evacuated* to a new region (part of the `mark-compact` phase).

So: `GC` is *active* and, at the same time, we *read* via `refA/refB`. When we do this reading we step on the `load-reference-barrier`, implemented [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/shenandoah/shenandoahBarrierSet.cpp#l128). Notice how internally it has some "filters" (via a bunch of `if/else` statements). Specifically:

- it checks if "evacuation is currently in progress". This is done via a thread local flag that is set when evacuation first starts. Let's suppose the answer to this is : yes.
- it checks if the object that we are currently operating on is in the "collection-set". This means it is currently marked as alive. Let's suppose this is "yes" also.
- the last check is to find out if this object was already "copied" to a different region (it was evacuated). Let's suppose the answer to this is "no", i.e. : `obj == fwd`.

At this point in time, a few things happen. First a copy is created and `mark` [becomes forwardee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002388/shenandoah-2-0-elimination-of-forwarding-pointer/64002389#64002389)

```
    refA refB            
        |               
 --------------      ---------
 |  forwardee | ---- | mark |            
 --------------      ---------    
    | i = 0 |        | i = 0 |  
    | j = 0 |        | j = 0 |  
    ---------        ---------
```

Only later in the code, would `refA` and `refB` be updated to point to the *new* (copied) object. But that means an interesting thing. It means that until `refA` and `refB` are actually made to point to the new object, the object that they currently point, is in the "collection set". So, if GC is active and even if the `forwardee` has been established, the `load-reference-barrier` still needs to do some work.

So the *very* smart people behind `Shenandoah` said this : why not update the references there, immediately after the `forwardee` has been established (or when the `forwardee` is already known for other references)? [And this is exactly what they did](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/shenandoah/shenandoahBarrierSet.cpp#l209).

Let's suppose we get back to our initial drawing:

```
refA refB            
    |               
---------
|  mark |                    
---------          
| i = 0 |          
| j = 0 |          
---------
```

And again, we "enable" all of the filter:

- there is a Thread that reads via `refA`
- GC is active
- the object behind `refA` and `refB` is alive.

This is what will happen with "self healing barriers":

```
       refB             refA
        |                |
 --------------      ---------
 |  forwardee | ---- | mark |            
 --------------      ---------    
    | i = 0 |        | i = 0 |  
    | j = 0 |        | j = 0 |  
    ---------        ---------
```

The difference is obvious: `refA` was moved to point to the new Object via `CAS`, on the spot.  If there is going to be a read *again* via `refA` (GC is still active), this will result in a much faster load-reference-barrier execution. Why? because `refA` points to an object that is *not* in the "collection set".

But this also means that if we read via `refB` and see that `fwd != obj` - the code can do the same trick and update the `refB` in place, at the time the first read happened via `refB`.

This improves performance according to the people familiar with the matter, and I trust them.