# Spring-MVC Jackson. Add field during bean serialization

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, custom-fields

jackson v1.9.13
spring 3.2.0
Hi,
I've been spending days trying to figure out how to add a field into a JSON from a bean during serialization.

It seems like a very basic feature but I bumped into rubber walls every route I took.

What I want to achieve:

**example bean:**

```
package org.mydomain;

public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String foo;
    public void setFoo( String inValue ) {
        foo = inValue;
    }    
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
{
    "_type" : "org.mydomain.MyBean",
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

I reckon that the simples way would be to extend a BeanSerializer write the "_type" property and delegate the super class serialization of the remaining fields. Problem is, the accessibility of methods and the "final" clause of some crucial methods makes it a quagmire.

I tried extending BeanSerializerBase, JsonSerializer, BeanSerializerModifier.

Every time I crash into some impenetrable 24-arguments-constructor or some non/mis-documented method.

Very frustrating.

Anyone has any idea on how to achieve the above bit?

**I'm using spring-mvc, therefore I need a pluggable solution via ObjectMapper configuration. I don't want to pollute my model or controller objects with json specific annotation or serialization logic.**

Thanks a lot.

N.

Comment: Another way to achieve this is discussed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo

Answer (score -1):

You can create a proxy class for `MyBean` and use it in place of `MyBean`. This doesn't require change in original class. You just need to replace the original `MyBean` object with proxy object. Although you can use without requiring an interface for `MyBean` but it's cleaner to use interface.

```
package org.mydomain;
public interface IMyBean{
    public String getFoo();
}
public class MyBean implements IMyBean,Serializable {
    private String foo;
    public void setFoo( String inValue ) {
        foo = inValue;
    }    
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
public class MyBeanProxy implements IMyBean,Serializable {

    private IMyBean myBean;
    private String type;
    public MyBeanProxy(IMyBean myBean, String type){
        this.myBean = myBean;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return myBean.getFoo();
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```