# Jackson custom JsonSerializer - conditionally call default serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

What I want is to use default BeanSerializer conditionally for my class's objects:

```
class MyCustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<AbstractEntity> {

    public MyCustomSerializer() {
        super(AbstractEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(AbstractEntity o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (someCondition()) {
           serializeNormalWay(); //how?
        } else {
           //custom serialization
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to do something like that:

```
serializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(o, jsonGenerator);
```

but this calls MyCustomSerializer's method and I have never-ending recursion.
How can I get appropriate Serializer object, that I could use for ordinary bean Serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires bit more complicated setup: instead of directly overriding serializer to use, you need to let Jackson create one, then take over.
This may be done by registering `BeanSerializerModifier` (via `Module`), method `modifySerializer(...)`. You will be given default serializer that would be used, and you can construct custom one, passing that default one.

Comment: OK, that was what I was looking for, thanks. I also found similar question with more detailed description:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo

Comment: Ok good. This is not a rare use case, but it is quite tricky to support wrt fallbacks. Glad you were able to get it worked out.