# Limit write size of String with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a list of objects with a field "description". This field can be huge (+3000 char) but I use it in the preview (I display only the 100 firsts char).

Is there a way in jackson to limit the size of a String on write ? I only want jackson to crop it to 100 chars. (No bean validation required here).

For exemple, if I have an object like this :

```
{
    "description" : "bla bla bla bla... + 3000 char"
}
```

Ideally I want it be cropped like thie :

```
{
    "description" : bla bla [max 100 chars] bla..."
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a custom serializer which can crop text if it exceeds a limit as shown below.

```
public class DescriptionSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if(value.length() > 100){
            value = value.substring(0, 100) + "...";
        }
        gen.writeString(value);
        
    }
    
}
```

And annotate your `description` field to use this custom serializer

```
public class Bean{
   
   @JsonSerialize(using=DescriptionSerializer.class)
   private String description

}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer.
What if I want to use my DTO in other cases where I need the full description ?

Comment: You can make use of [Jackson Views](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) as explained in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978724/jackson-json-de-serialization-with-views)

Comment: Yes, that will do the job :-)
Thank you !