# FasterXml - JsonSerializer HashMap

Tags: java, fasterxml, jsonserializer

I'm using jackson-databind version 2.12.3 to serialize the return of an object that should return like this:

```json
{
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2":"value2",
  "links":{
    "field":{
      "href":"/link"
    },
    "test":{
      "href":"/test"
    }
  }
}
```

My classes are these:

```java
public class HrefType  {
  private String href = null;
  ...
}
```

```java
public class Link extends HashMap<String, HrefType>  {
  private HrefType field = null;
  ...
}
```

```java
public class MyObject  {
  private String field1 = null;
  private String field2 = null;
  private Link links = null;
  ...
}
```

The return is myObject:

```java
  MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
  myObject.setField1("value1");
  myObject.setField2("value2");

  Link link = new Link();
  link.setField(new HrefType().href("/link"));
  link.put("test",new HrefType().href("/test"));

  myObject.setLinks(link);
```

However with the default ObjectMapper the "link.setField" is ignored and the returned json is:

```json
{
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2":"value2",
  "links":{
    "test":{
      "href":"/test"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing some tests with JsonSerializer but couldn't do something generic for all classes that extend HashMap (these classes are generated from BerlinGroup's PSD2 YAML, so I wouldn't want to change the generated class).

Is there a generic way to do it, or should I make a serialize class for each class that extends the HashMap?

Comment: Do you have a **getter** for the "field" property on the Link class (>A getter makes a private field serializable/deserializable) ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco yes:
  @JsonProperty("field")
  public HrefType getField() {
    return field;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31057934/4611944) I developed this generic method of making for all objects that extend a Map:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

    public MyClassSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer) {
        this.defaultSerializer = (defaultSerializer);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object src, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        Field[] fields = src.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                boolean fieldAccessible = field.isAccessible();
                field.setAccessible(true);

                Object object = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, src);
                if (object != null && object instanceof Map) {

                    Field[] fieldsMap = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                    Map map = (Map) object;
                    for (Field fieldMap : fieldsMap) {
                        boolean fieldMapAccessible = fieldMap.isAccessible();
                        fieldMap.setAccessible(true);

                        Object fieldObject = ReflectionUtils.getField(fieldMap, object);
                        if (fieldObject != null) {
                            map.put(fieldMap.getName(), fieldObject);
                        }
                        fieldMap.setAccessible(fieldMapAccessible);
                    }
                }
                field.setAccessible(fieldAccessible);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        defaultSerializer.serialize(src, gen, provider);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> handledType() {
        return Object.class;
    }
}
```

which goes through all fields, when I find one that extends from a Map I go through all the fields of this one and add it to the Map ignoring the object's fields, so the Serializer works perfectly.

EDIT: to Deserializer properly I do this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ResolvableDeserializer;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class MyClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements ResolvableDeserializer {

    private JsonDeserializer defaultDeserializer;

    protected MyClassDeserializer(JsonDeserializer deserializer) {
        this.defaultDeserializer = deserializer;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Object obj = defaultDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                boolean fieldAccessible = field.isAccessible();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object object = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, obj);
                if (object != null && object instanceof Map) {

                    Field[] fieldsMap = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                    Map map = (Map) object;
                    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                        for (Field fieldMap : fieldsMap) {
                            if (fieldMap.getName().equals((String) key)) {

                                if (fieldMap.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("serialVersionUID")) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                boolean fieldMapAccessible = fieldMap.isAccessible();
                                fieldMap.setAccessible(true);

                                Object fieldObject = ReflectionUtils.getField(fieldMap, object);
                                if (fieldObject == null) {
                                    fieldMap.set(object, map.get(key));
                                    map.replace(key, null);
                                }
                                fieldMap.setAccessible(fieldMapAccessible);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                        if(map.get(keys[i])==null) {
                            map.remove(keys[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                field.setAccessible(fieldAccessible);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Composition

First of all, I suggest you use *composition* instead of *inheritance* in this particular case. Your code will look like the next:

```java
    private class Link {
        private final HrefType field;
        private final HashMap<String, HrefType> test;

        public Link(HrefType field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        public HrefType getField() {
            return field;
        }

        public HashMap<String, HrefType> getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    }
```

And serialization will work fine, as expected.

### Serializer

But in case, if you can't change the original code, you might to write your own `StdSerializer`. For example:

```java
    private class LinkSerializer extends StdSerializer<Link> {

        public LinkSerializer() {
            super(Link.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Link link, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            final HrefType field = link.getField();
            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("field", field);
            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("test", new HashMap<>(link));
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
```

And declare it over your `Link` class:

```java
    @JsonSerialize(using = LinkSerializer.class)
    private static class Link extends HashMap<String, HrefType> {
        private final HrefType field;

        public Link(HrefType field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        public HrefType getField() {
            return field;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In both cases it works, but as they are generated classes from a YAML I would not want to have to change them every time they are generated in some update. Is there any other way to do something generic for all classes that extend a hashmap?

Comment: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/jackson-modules/jackson/src/main/java/com/baeldung/jackson/inheritance
Here are several examples of the implementation of inheritance in Jackson.
Maybe you find what you want. But, to be honest, I didn't find what could solve your problem in a simple way.

Comment: I'll try something, tks a lot.