# JsonGenerator write object and string field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to generate a JSON string from an object and adding a field on the same level.

```
{
    "objField1": "objValue1",
    "objField2": "objValue2",
    "stringField": "stringValue"
}
```

Here's the code snippet:

```java
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonGenerator generator = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(writer).useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
// mapper.writeValue(generator, responseObj); // tried this without success instead of the following
generator.writeObject(obj);
generator.writeStringField("stringField", "stringValue");
generator.close();
writer.close();
```

But all I get are the fields from my object:

```
{
    "objField1": "objValue1",
    "objField2": "objValue2"
}
```

Comment: JSONObject inner1 = new JSONObject();
inner1.put("string", "string value"); you can try like this.

Comment: How to set it on the generator then? `generator.writeObject(inner1);`? That didn't work. Same result.

Comment: i did not understand your question. please tell me. how do you want?

Comment: The first code block is what I want. The last is what I get. And the second is the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void serialize(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen,
                SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
                JsonGenerationException {           
            jgen.writeStartObject();                        
            serializeFields(bean, jgen, provider);
            jgen.writeStringField("extraField", "extraFieldValue"); 
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
```

look at this link:
[Jackson: How to add custom property to the JSON without modifying the POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo)

Comment: Where does `serializeFields` come from?

Comment: It's not a great answer. It's from BeanSerializerBase, which cannot be constructed with @JsonSerializer, as it has no default constructor