# How to make Jackson ignore properties if the getters throw exceptions

Tags: java, jackson

I have a multitude of classes coming from a vendor that like to randomly throw RuntimeExceptions on property access.

```
public Object getSomeProperty() {
    if (!someObscureStateCheck()) {
        throw new IllegalStateExcepion();
    }
    return calculateTheValueOfProperty(someRandomState);
}
```

I cannot change the classes, cannot add annotations and it's unrealistic to define mixins for every single class as this part of stack changes fairly often.

How do I make Jackson ignore a property if its getter throws an Exception?

Comment: Is it possible to use try catch?

Comment: I'd investigate setting up your object mapper with a custom `JsonGenerator`, possibly by extending and modifying [the default implementation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonGeneratorImpl.html) to ignore/handle exceptions differently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To perform [custom serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15365957/2646526) in Jackson, you can [register a module](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules) with a [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.7.1/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.java) that specifies whatever modifications are needed.  In your case, [`BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.7.1/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanPropertyWriter.java#L630) is the method responsible for serializing individual fields, so you should make your own `BeanPropertyWriter` that ignores exceptions on field serialization, and register a module with a `BeanSerializerModifier` that uses [`changeProperties`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.7.1/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.java#L47) to replace all default `BeanPropertyWriter` instances with your own implementation.  The following example demonstrates:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JacksonIgnorePropertySerializationExceptions {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
                return beanProperties.stream().map(bpw -> new BeanPropertyWriter(bpw) {
                    @Override
                    public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
                        try {
                            super.serializeAsField(bean, gen, prov);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(String.format("ignoring %s for field '%s' of %s instance", e.getClass().getName(), this.getName(), bean.getClass().getName()));
                        }
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }));

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, new VendorClass());
    }

    public static class VendorClass {
        public String getNormalProperty() {
            return "this is a normal getter";
        }

        public Object getProblematicProperty() {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this getter throws an exception");
        }

        public String getAnotherNormalProperty() {
            return "this is a another normal getter";
        }
    }
}
```

The above code outputs the following, using Jackson 2.7.1 and Java 1.8:

```
ignoring java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException for field 'problematicProperty' of JacksonIgnorePropertySerializationExceptions$VendorClass instance
{"normalProperty":"this is a normal getter","anotherNormalProperty":"this is a another normal getter"}
```

showing that `getProblematicProperty`, which throws an `IllegalStateException`, will be omitted from the serialized value.