# How can I tell Jackson to skip invalid records during deserialization?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON file containing millions of records.  I'd like to use a Jackson iterator to read the records one at a time and perform an action for each one.  Here's the code so far.

```
MappingIterator<MyClass> iterator = new ObjectMapper()
        .readerFor(MyClass.class)
        .readValues(file);

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    MyClass object = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

The problem is that a few of the records are invalid due to missing quotes or illegal characters.  This causes Jackson to throw an exception and quit.  How can I tell Jackson to skip these records and continue to parse the remaining valid records?

Comment: don't you want to add try-catch to handle `RuntimeJsonMappingException`? and if it has cause `JsonMappingException` just skip it?

Comment: I tried that.  I get an exception from iterator.next().  And then I get the same exception again from iterator.hasNext().  That makes it impossible to continue parsing the file.

Answer (score 1):

try `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` or you may need
JsonFilter or customize serialization

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria
- [How to make Jackson ignore properties if the getters throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359430/how-to-make-jackson-ignore-properties-if-the-getters-throw-exceptions)
  ie:

> ```
> @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
> @JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
> public class User {
>     private Long id;
>     private String name;
>     private User() {}
>     constructor, setter, getter 
> }
> ```

```
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
            JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
            final Long id = node.get("id").asLong();
            final String name = node.get("name").asText();
            return new User(id, name);
        } catch (JsonParseException ex) {
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input = "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"valid\"}," +
            " {\"id\": 2, \"name\": invalid}," +
            " {\"id\": 3, \"name\": \"valid\"}]";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<User> users = objectMapper.readValue(input, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, User.class));
    users.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output

```
1 valid
null
null
3 valid
```

So you just ignore/filter null in collection

Comment: There aren't any unknown properties in the data.  The only issue is poorly formatted JSON.

Comment: I see, so you have to customize deserialize by your own with this annotation
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourCuztomeDeserializer.class)
So using try/catch block you can skip all row which raises an exception cuz incorrect JSON format
You can follow these example to see how they customize serialization
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359430/how-to-make-jackson-ignore-properties-if-the-getters-throw-exceptions

Comment: I tried the custom deserializer, and it's also not helping.  After I catch an exception in the deserializer, Jackson then tries to parse the next record starting right after the first illegal character in the file, which isn't the start of a new record.  This causes iterator.hasNext() to throw an exception.

Comment: I just add my example, may help for u

Comment: Try replacing `{\"id\": 2, \"name\": invalid}` with `{\"id\": 2, \"name: \"invalid\"}` (missing a closing quote) and you'll see why this approach won't work.

Comment: I see, hmm is there any idea to determine each record? like pair "{", "}" may back to string process =))

Comment: I might need to resort to something like bracket matching.  I've seen a few times of malformed JSON so far, including a missing closing quote, illegal characters in attribute names, and at least one instance of a duplicate closing bracket.