# Jackson ObjectMapper non blocking processing

Tags: java, api, jackson, response, objectmapper

I am trying to process a huge number of star array responses from one API, it can contain for example 4K of objects, and I am using **Jackson ObjectMapper** to map the response to the List of my Objects. Here is a simplified example of my class:

```
 public class MyObject {
    
     private Long price;

 }
```

Because in odoo you work with just objects is theoretically possible to put in the field which should contain just numbers a String. I would like to handle cases when for example one response will be incorrect but the other will be sent correctly (5,4,1,"not number",..). In this case, I would like to **just log the error for the user and process all the other responses**. I was wondering if there is some setting for the ObjectMapper or if you don't have others ideas on how to deal with this.

thx for your advice.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far and how you consume the api

Comment: Basically, API is consumed throw XmlRpcClient, which returns just a basic Object containing a list of objects I need to map. There is not a problem, I managed to do it throw the Jackson ObjectMapper, and it will successfully map it in case all objects are correct. But when at least one is incorrect I will get JsonProcessingException. What I need is to get all the other correct repossess.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a basic Object'? Is it text / a `String`? Is it a Java `Object`?

Please provide an example if possible

Comment: try this answers: [skip-invalid-records-during-deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836456/how-can-i-tell-jackson-to-skip-invalid-records-during-deserialization)