# Builder design pattern : Required attributes

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it important to define required attributes on the builder as `final`  ? 
( code performance )

This is an example illustrating my question :

```
public class User {
private final String firstName; // required
private final String lastName; // required
private final int age; // optional
private final String phone; // optional
private final String address; // optional

private User(UserBuilder builder) {
    this.firstName = builder.firstName;
    this.lastName = builder.lastName;
    this.age = builder.age;
    this.phone = builder.phone;
    this.address = builder.address;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public static class UserBuilder {
    private final String firstName; // required
    private final String lastName;  // required
    private int age;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public UserBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public UserBuilder age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder phone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder address(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    public User build() {
        return new User(this);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: No. It is not. Required attributes should be checked in `build()`. As should any other requirements.

Comment: Yes , i know required attributes should be in the constructor of the UserBuilder class , but defining required attributes as final does not effect code performance  ??

Comment: No, they should not! A builder should have a **no args** constructor. The state of the builder should be checked in the `build()` method before building the target class. Having arguments in a builder constructor is both inconvenient and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "Usually not".

> You should use `final` based on clear design and readability rather
>   than for performance reasons.

[Does use of final keyword in Java improve the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance)