# should I must add final keyword when declaring a ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: java, java-8, final, concurrenthashmap

When I declare a `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java 8 class  like this:

```
private final static ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Integer> signRatioMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

I found without `final` it doesn't work fine. should I add final keywords? what is the advantage?

Comment: If you can make something final, it's generally better to do so, but static state (like this map) is a serious design smell; state should almost always be per-instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, making a variable `final` is a good coding practice and also may lead to some performance benefits (see the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279442/508328 for details).

In your case, however, the situation is slightly different because Java's implementation of hash map can only grow its internal structure and never shrinks down, which leads to the continuous deterioration of its scan performance. So if your map is going to be changed often, it'd be better to recreate it now and then, and in that case it can't be `final`.

Comment: Recreating the map would defeat the purpose of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, as that can’t be an atomic operation, hence, not thread safe. That’s why the variable should be declared `final`, to document that the author understood that point.

Comment: @Holger still it can be done in a `synchronized` block, but that's far beyond the OP's original question :-)

Comment: A `synchronized` block would only work against code also using `synchronized` blocks using the same object. In other words, you’d have to put almost every access to the map into `synchronized` blocks, which, as said, would defeat the purpose of a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Atomic updates can only work when they are not mixed with non-atomic updates.

Answer (score 1):

The `Final` keyword does nothing but prevent a variable from being reassigned. If you don't need to reassign the variable, make it final.